# Hashicorp Vault - Agent Injector - does it make sense?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, hashicorp-vault

I have basic and fundamental question regards to Hashicorp Vault. I would like to inject some secrets (password to database) from Vault to container with Spring application.

I have prepared a specific annotations for using Vault with Kubernetes and everything works fine, saving PASSWORD variable as environment allows me using in application.properties file.

```
template:
metadata:
  annotations:
    vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject: "true"
    vault.hashicorp.com/role: "myapp-role"
    vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-foo: "secret/creds"
    vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-template-foo: |
      {{`{{- with secret "secret/creds" -}}
      PASSWORD={{ .Data.passcode }}
      {{- end }}`}}
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ $appName }}
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
spec:
  containers:
    - name: {{ $appName }}
      image: "{{ .Values.vvvv.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.vvvv.image.tag }}"
      command: ["/bin/bash", "-c","while read line; do export $line; done < /vault/secrets/foo; /usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh run"]
      volumeMounts:
        - name: application-properties
          mountPath: /usr/local/tomcat/lib/application.properties
          subPath: application.properties
      ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
```

the question is pretty simple, does it make sense? inject agent saves the file with PLAIN text password in the /vault path, so everybody can see this secret... another question, how can I rotate credentials for application? should I use specific controllers inside the spring application right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it definitely makes sense as the purpose is to avoid hard coding credentials in the spec.

> inject agent saves the file with PLAIN text password in the /vault
> path, so everybody can see this secret.

Even in bare metal servers or cloud instances, credentials are saved in plain text. In case of k8s, it is inside a container. In both scenarios, you would control who can access your instances or k8s pods. Only authorised personnel shall have the required access to pods in production cluster(s).

> how can I rotate credentials for application

The vault agent injector runs a sidecar container along with your app container in the same pod. Its purpose is to look for any changes in the vault secret at regular intervals. If you do a `kubectl describe po <pod-name>` you'll find a sidecar container `vault-agent` running.

```
kubectl get po app-example-deployment-7c4b45cf8-4fkr7
NAME                                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
app-example-deployment-7c4b45cf8-4fkr7   2/2     Running   0          166m
```

`kubectl describe pod app-example-deployment-7c4b45cf8-4fkr7` :

```
...
vault-agent:
    Container ID:  docker://b6f9df32ed903d684c972401f41e15a8f6b1bec62aa111bfd9c693159af1ff09
    Image:         vault:1.7.0
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://vault@sha256:635cf1c3f9b10fe03aad375f94cc61f63d74a189662165285a8bf1c189ea04b8
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      /bin/sh
      -ec
    Args:
      echo ${VAULT_CONFIG?} | base64 -d > /home/vault/config.json && vault agent -config=/home/vault/config.json
    State:          Running
      Started:      Tue, 13 Apr 2021 15:40:10 +0100
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      cpu:     500m
      memory:  128Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:     250m
      memory:  64Mi
    Environment:
      VAULT_LOG_LEVEL:   info
      VAULT_LOG_FORMAT:  standard
...
```

After successfully fetching the secret from vault during deployment:

```
kubectl exec -it app-example-deployment-7c4b45cf8-4fkr7 -c app -- cat /vault/secrets/db-creds
mongodb+srv://testUser:testPass@test-5xxxx.mongodb.net/testDb
```

If I change the kv secret in Vault with password set to, let's say "testPass2", I need not do anything as the `vault-agent` sidecar container will update it for me automatically.

```
kubectl exec -it app-example-deployment-7c4b45cf8-4fkr7 -c app -- cat /vault/secrets/db-creds
mongodb+srv://testUser:testPass2@test-5xxxx.mongodb.net/testDb
```

In the `vault-agent` sidecar container logs, you'll see something like.

```
kubectl logs app-example-deployment-7c4b45cf8-4fkr7 -c vault-agent --follow
2021-04-13T14:40:10.426Z [INFO]  sink.file: creating file sink
2021-04-13T14:40:10.426Z [INFO]  sink.file: file sink configured: path=/home/vault/.vault-token mode=-rw-r-----
==> Vault agent started! Log data will stream in below:

==> Vault agent configuration:

                     Cgo: disabled
               Log Level: info
                 Version: Vault v1.7.0
             Version Sha: 4e222b85c40a810b74400ee3c54449479e32bb9f

2021-04-13T14:40:10.426Z [INFO]  template.server: starting template server
[INFO] (runner) creating new runner (dry: false, once: false)
2021-04-13T14:40:10.427Z [INFO]  auth.handler: starting auth handler
2021-04-13T14:40:10.427Z [INFO]  auth.handler: authenticating
2021-04-13T14:40:10.427Z [INFO]  sink.server: starting sink server
[INFO] (runner) creating watcher
2021-04-13T14:40:10.437Z [INFO]  auth.handler: authentication successful, sending token to sinks
2021-04-13T14:40:10.437Z [INFO]  auth.handler: starting renewal process
2021-04-13T14:40:10.437Z [INFO]  template.server: template server received new token
[INFO] (runner) stopping
[INFO] (runner) creating new runner (dry: false, once: false)
[INFO] (runner) creating watcher
[INFO] (runner) starting
2021-04-13T14:40:10.437Z [INFO]  sink.file: token written: path=/home/vault/.vault-token
2021-04-13T14:40:10.439Z [INFO]  auth.handler: renewed auth token
[INFO] (runner) rendered "(dynamic)" => "/vault/secrets/db-creds"
2021-04-13T15:23:43.315Z [INFO]  auth.handler: renewed auth token
[INFO] (runner) rendered "(dynamic)" => "/vault/secrets/db-creds"
2021-04-13T16:07:16.191Z [INFO]  auth.handler: renewed auth token
```

Comment: So far so good, but it does not reflect in the service which is using the secrets. Any workarounds for that? ( to maybe trigger a service restart)

Comment: Yeah that would depend on the application how to handle the secret refresh. An example would be, if you export the secret's value into an Env variable and your application if referring to that to do a specific job, it'd notice the new value. Your mileage may vary though.